# How to add "Header" in all pages in the PDF

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a project wherein I have to include the "Header" at the top of the PDF of every page using XSL. Anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:
[Tutorial on XSL page areas](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/xslfo_areas.asp)
Basically you have to add the header content to fo:region-before.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions on [simple page layouts](http://cnx.org/content/m43650/latest/) . You have to put the header into `region-before`. And checkout the examples which come with Apache fop.

And please provide a code example. A start might be given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548663/cant-generate-pdf-with-apache-fop). It works fine in Windows 7.